# Docker ADD then RUN

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I'm building a docker image for our specific implementation of an ElasticSearch server.  It requires config files.  In my Dockerfile, I have the following commands:

```
 RUN mkdir /elasticsearch/plugins

 ADD plugins/es_plugins.tar /elasticsearch/plugins
 RUN \
      cd /elasticsearch/plugins && \
      tar -xvf es_plugins.tar && \
      rm -f es_plugins.tar
```

Docker build succeeds on the mkdir, and the ADD. But fails with a tar error "es_plugins.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory"

This is my first time with Docker.  Any ideas why the "ADD" shows successful but the RUN fails?

Comment: Not sure but try this `ADD plugins/es_plugins.tar /elasticsearch/plugins/plugins.tar`

Comment: It's expecting the <dest> to be a directory.  When I tried this, it created a directory called plugins.tar

Comment: The other thing to try is `(cd /elasticsearch/plugins ; tar -xvf ./es_plugins.tar )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took an hour, but I figured out how to run my container and drop into a shell.

Seems that when I do "ADD file.tar /destination/dir"  it actually moves the files/directories inside the tar into the destination. Which is what I wanted, but I am surprised.  I will have to do more research.

Comment: the [ADD](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add) instruction will extract files if the source is a recognized compression format. If you do not wish that behavior, use the [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#copy) instruction instead.

Comment: Bloody hell, that's so unintuitive. Thanks for the heads up. I would never have guesses that a command called ADD would decompress archives. I actually read TFM more than once and managed not to notice this nuance.